# PHP simplexml_load_file() does this need a @ prefix

Tags: php

I am working with a previous developers code and a lot of his code hide errors with the `@`

One example being:

```
if(!file_exists($filename)) 
    throw new Exception("file '$filename' does not exist.");

$xmlObject = @simplexml_load_file($filename);       
if($xmlObject === false) 
    throw new Exception("Could not load '$filename' check syntax and file has read permission.");
```

I understand that using the `@` hides errors but is this good practice or bad?

Comment: you don't want errors to be displayed on production environments, but you want them for sure while debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's bad.  You should always check to make sure everything is legit.  Developing good clean code will allow you to identify issues when something does go wrong.  By using the @ it will suppress those errors which could be caused by something else entirely.  You would never know and troubleshooting becomes that more difficult.

Taking your example above.

```
$xmlObject = @simplexml_load_file($filename);
```

That person is already checking if the file exists.  You could probably remove that @ symbol and change it up with try catch blocks.

```
Try {
  $xmlObject = simplexml_load_file($filename);
catch....
```

Comment: try/catch only catches exceptions, right?  simplexml_load_file throws E_WARNING according to the docs.  http://php.net/simplexml-load-file .  The correct way to suppress errors for this method is to use `libxml_use_internal_errors(true)`

Comment: Good call, I knew there was a few methods that needed some special handling to avoid using the '@' symbol.

Comment: Beside that using @ is bad practice and sould be avoided, it's slower than try/catch because the parser has to change it's error_reporting to null and back to the defined. (Certain if used more often in one runtime)

Answer (score 2):

As long as other error catching is in place, such as in the example above, using the `@` is acceptable because it hides PHP's standard error output.

However, using `@` to hide errors but doing nothing to remedy them is considered bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Very bad.

First you develop the code. Then you begin testing it and if there is something wrong you want to know what is wrong by seeing an error. So you do not want to hide them.

If you have had the developing and debugging state and want to put it online you have to turn the errors off. This can be doing by:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');
error_reporting( null );
?>
```

The users won't see any error now. Better is adding this in the .htaccess file:

```
# Turn off the errors
php_flag display_startup_errors off
php_flag display_errors off
```

So then the errors are already hidden, so `@` is not needed.

I cannot remember a state where you want to hide errors.

Comment: Sometimes function like the one above do throw errors that you cannot really check for and that is why using an @ symbol would come into play.  A better approach is try catch blocks.  This will also prevent WSOD by turning your errors off.